# How to send tailored emails with python and mailgun (HTTP method)

Tags: python-3.x, mailgun

How do you pass values from python to an html template in mailgun

```
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox<...>.mailgun.org/messages",
        auth=("api", "API-KEY"),
        data={"from": "SENDER",
            "to": "RECEIVER",
            "subject": "test email ",
            "template": "TEST",
            "v:name":"the user name ",
            "v:this_link": "https://google.com"})


send_simple_message()
```

The email template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>v:name</h3>
    <a href="v:this_link"> link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

while testing I get the email but none of the `v:` variable are changed, according to [mailgun docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#attaching-data-to-messages) you have to do it this way but they do not specify how to define the variables in the html template

I tried the following

```
v:name
{{v:name}}
```

but it does not seem to work although I receive the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing it some what wrong in the html part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    <a href="{{this_link}}"> link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

keep the python part as is